# How to get second to last parameter of previous command in bash?

Tags: bash, command-history, line-editor

I can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to get the last parameter of the previous command, but is there an equally convenient short-cut to get the second to last parameter?

Comment: You might be interested in History Expansion.  See `LESS='+/^HISTORY EXPANSION' man bash`.  It doesn't quite handle this exact use case in one shortcut for every case, but it has lots of related goodies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `M-.` is bound to `yank-last-arg`. `M-C-y` is bound to `yank-nth-arg`, where `n` defaults to one. With a prefix argument of `-1` you can, indeed, yank the second last word of the previous line.

Comment: Thank you, that allowed me to create a binding that did what I wanted.